# Why does my if statement get stuck on the first value?

Tags: php, if-statement

I wanted to set a `$levelNumber` based on the number of Lessons. So I did the following:

```
  <?php
    $s = "Lesson 001: Vocabulary";
    preg_match("/([0-9]+)/", $s, $matches);
    echo $matches[1]; // => 001

    if ($matches[1] >= 060) {
      $levelNumber = "2"; 
    } elseif ($matches[1] >= 120) {
      $levelNumber = "3";
    } elseif ($matches[1] >= 180) {
      $levelNumber = "4";
    } elseif ($matches[1] >= 240) {
      $levelNumber = "5";
    } elseif ($matches[1] >= 300) {
      $levelNumber = "6";
    } elseif ($matches[1] >= 360) {
      $levelNumber = "7";
    } else {
      $levelNumber = "1";
    }
  ?>
```

But right now no matter how big the lesson is (e.g. `180`) `$levelNumber` always outputs `2`. And it outputs `1` when the lesson is under `048`. I'm really confused.

This is the correct level with lesson:

> Level 1: Lessons 1 to 60
>
> Level 2: Lessons 61 to 120
>
> Level 3: Lessons 121 to 180
>
> Level 4: Lessons 181 to 240
>
> Level 5: Lessons 241 to 300
>
> Level 6: Lessons 301 to 360
>
> Level 7: Lessons 361 to 420

Comment: for your code it outputs levelnumber = 1

Comment: Because the every number that is >= 60 (`matches[1]`) results in `levelNumber = 2` basing on the logic you provide. Just reverse order the if block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of your problem is 060 is an octal represetation.  That explains the 48 problem.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

And, as everyone else pointed out, you can't use a bunch of >= in your if statement.

Comment: Take a look at the link you referenced on strings vs numbers, it seems to indicate that the string will be converted to a number implicitly for the comparison (that was always my understanding, maybe I am wrong or misreading) - if you can clarify for me and/or remove that bit I will upvote the answer for the catch on octal representation.

Comment: I'm on my phone so I can't test but you may have an issue with 061 being treated as octal which is less than 61.

Comment: I agree with you on the octal part, that is a great catch.  It's the part about "matches array contains strings not numbers" that I was concerned might be incorrect.

Comment: I was thinkin the string "061"  would be treated as octal but it's not http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#111522

Answer (score 1):

Consider the logic flow in your statements.

When the line `if ($matches[1] >= 060)` is encountered and the value of `$matches[1]` is 180, the condition is `true` so the code block executes.  Thus, `$levelNumber` is assigned the value "2".

Because you are using `elseif` for the remaining conditions, they are never evaluated (the first condition was already satisfied).

The easiest solution is probably to change the order of your `if` statements to check for the larger values first.